# Navigation drawer icon gets disappeared on setting CustomView in actionbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-actionbar-compat

Why navigation drawer icon gets disappeared on setting customView by

```
actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.blah);
```

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, you don't post any code, so I have to assume stuff here. So if you can update your question and show actual code!!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Depending on what your custom Action Bar will do, you might want to disable these!
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

    // Here is how you can get specific items from your custom view!
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    titleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

    ...

    // MAKE SURE THESE ARE SET!! BOTH OF THEM!!
    actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

The biggest issue is probably the code at the very end. Please make sure you have that code!